Why doesn't use_exisiting_column parameter resolve conflicts here?
I'm using declarative single table inheritance for a common User base class with different user types broken into derived classes. Two of the derived classes have an identically named and -typed foreign key field, so I used the use_existing_column parameter set to True. Running migrate on the models produces:

sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Column 'company_id' on class SystemUser conflicts with existing column 'user.company_id'.  If using Declarative, consider using the use_existing_column parameter of mapped_column() to resolve conflicts.

I tried each field from their respective models individually and the migrate command executed successfully. I tried adding the field to the common base class and received the same error. Removing the foreign_key parameter from mapped_column didn't change anything either.
from typing import Optional, List
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.orm as so
from app import db

class Company(db.Model):
    id: so.Mapped[int] = so.mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    #
    # More stuff
    #

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id: so.Mapped[int] = so.mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    role : so.Mapped[str] = so.mapped_column(sa.String(16))
    #
    # More stuff
    #

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "user",
        "polymorphic_on": role,
    }

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}:{self.email}:{self.role}"


# A System User is a User
# A System User has a Company
class SystemUser(User):
    company_id: so.Mapped[int] = so.mapped_column(sa.ForeignKey("company.id"), nullable=True, use_existing_column=True)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "system_user",
    }


# A Loan Officer is a User
# A Loan Officer has a Company
class LoanOfficer(User):
    company_id: so.Mapped[int] = so.mapped_column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey("company.id"), nullable=True, use_existing_column=True)
    company: so.Mapped[Company] = so.relationship(back_populates="loan_officers")
    #
    # More stuff
    #

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "loan_officer",
    }

pyproject.toml shows that packages are up-to-date:
[tool.poetry]
name = "mortgageplus"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Miles Johnson <milesgjohnson@proton.me>"]
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"
Flask = "^3.0.3"
Flask-WTF = "^1.2.1"
python-dotenv = "^1.0.1"
flask-sqlalchemy = "^3.1.1"
pymysql = "^1.1.1"
flask-login = "^0.6.3"
sqlalchemy-utils = "^0.41.2"
flask-migrate = "^4.0.7"


[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"


Is this the code that produces the error? I don't et an error if I create the models via metadata.create_all() (You are running Flask-Migrate I presume, but both approaches should behave similarly).
